# How to forward to domain? htaccess trick

Tags: php, html, dns

I am looking for a script on my website, I want every link to forward to my domain. 
It is hard to explain but it have to look like this: domain com/text (forwards to:) ==> domain com
and every other "text" forwards to this domain every random
domain .com/random => domain com
domain com/other => domain com

Can somebody send me this script?

Comment: If you can be a little more clear about what you want I can help you. So you're saying no matter what the links on your webpage say you want them to forward to one domain?

Comment: Yes. Every single subpage forwards to main domain. So what ever i type doman.com/here will forward me to domain.com I have heard that you can make it in htaccess

Comment: So you mean when someone types in to the browser a url it forwards them to one place? you are not talking about links on a webpage?

Comment: I am talking about links on webpage. Every random text typed domain.com/here forwards to domain.com So what ever I type there will forward me to domain.com

Comment: Ok you can use one of my examples or read that link. If yo tell me exactly what language you want i show you an example with that language. Also if my answer helped you please accept it :)

Comment: are you now talking about "links on webpage" (which would be HTML elements) or "forwarding URLs by htaccess" (which would be a server side config to send custom HTTP responses, and also unclear because you didn't say us which server you're using)? also, no, nobody "can send you this script" because there's no script and this is not a "work for free for me" site. got issues with programming? we help you fix it. got no idea what you're talking about yourself? think about it again, learn the vocab (link != url), then ask so we understand you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like Redirect 301, you can see examples here http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/how-can-i-do-a-301-redirect

Answer (score 0):

[301 url redirection is your solution](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/url-redirect.htm)

```
.htaccess

Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm /newfile.htm
```

&

```
php
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com" ); 
?>
```